Equivalence of axion to fermion couplings
In order to solve the Strong CP problem through the axion, we introduce the axion-gluon coupling
$$
\dfrac{a(x)}{f_a} \text{Tr}\, G\tilde{G}.\tag{1}
$$
In a similar fashion, we may introduce the axion-photon coupling as
$$
\dfrac{a(x)}{f_\gamma} \text{Tr}\, F\tilde{F} .\tag{2}
$$
Now, in this reference I found that the axion-fermion coupling is
$$
\dfrac{\partial_\mu a(x)}{f_Q} \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \gamma^5 \psi. \tag{91}
$$
Now, why is the axion coupling to fermions derivative? Why can't we use a "normal" coupling, as in
$$
\dfrac{a(x)}{f_Q} \bar{\psi} \psi. \tag{4}
$$
Is this to respect Lorentz invariance, or some similarly nice properties?
Edit:
In many papers, like this one, I have only seen couplings of the form
$$
i\dfrac{a(x)}{f_Q} \bar{\psi} \gamma^5 \psi. \tag{5}
$$
Is there some kind of equivalence between (91) and (5)? In other words, is there an equivalence between pseudoscalar and pseudovector couplings?
